# VisualStudio Could not load file or assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VisualStudio 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 on both of my computers, and I use both of them to work on a project (not simultaneously), but now when I open a form on my laptop to edit its design it shows me this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I haven't found any solution to this problem and I've already tried to delete the contents of this folder `(C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache)` as advised by another thread on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if you are referring the strong name of the dll or not ?
i.e. Check the name and version of the dll on your system and the one referred in csproj.

If the strong name is not same it means you need to correct your references or need to install that dll with version 1.1.0.0